# Enable and Disable Rows in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I was playing around with enabling and disabling rows in a datagrid:

```
public IEnumerable GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)  
{  
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;  
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;  
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)  
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;  
        if (null != row) yield return row;  
    }  
}  

private void DisableGridRows()
{  
    bool enableRow = false;  
    var rows = GetDataGridRows(myGrid);  
    foreach (DataGridRow dataRow in rows)  
    {  
        if (!enableRow)  
        { 
            dataRow.IsEnabled = false;  
            enableRow = true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            enableRow = false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The issue I am running into is that sometimes rows don't get disabled. When running in debug I can't duplicate the problem so it is making think something is going on with the grid not updating.

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have `Virtualization` turned on, if so `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` will only return visible rows that are on screen not all the rows that exist in your underlying collection, A Xaml `Trigger` would be a cleaner way to do this

Comment: I'll check that, but what you describe is what I am seeing. I thought about a XAML trigger but there will be various conditions on what rows to enable or disable. I was thinking of perhaps a filter.

Comment: Yup, looks like it was the Virtualization causing the issue